# Gnome shell: automating windows and placement

Tags: gnome, firefox, automation

First off, sorry if this isn't the best formed question. I've tried to research the best part of the stack to focus on, but I'm still not 100% sure I've got it.

So, I'll explain the outcome I'm after:

On Ubuntu 20.04 (GNOME Shell 3.36.9 / Xorg) I have a window configuration I set up every morning (for our company stand up): one Firefox window snapped to the right column with a URL open, and one snapped to the left column with another URL.

I understand how to open a URL in a browser, but the thing I want to automate is a little different:

1. Open a *new* browser window in a *new* workspace (ideally at the top of the workspaces)
2. Snap that window to the right
3. Open another *new* browser window in the same workspace, snapped left
4. Have both browser windows open the URLs I'm after
5. Bonus points for opening them in the Firefox containers I use, but I appreciate that's a Firefox issue, not a Gnome one.

Ideally this would be something I can script using bash or python.

My question is: is this sort of thing even possible? What APIs or tooling should I be looking at, or are there projects that do this sort of thing already? It seems like a useful thing to have, as everyone must have a set of common window setups they want to save.

My lack of understanding of the Gnome ecosystem is making this hard to search for.

Comment: may not do all you ask but have you looked at the GNOME extension Put Windows in association with `Startup Applications`?

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate windows using `wmctrl` and `xdotool`, and in addition, daemons such as `devilspie` and `devilspie2` allow you to define rules for specific windows. When a window is created that matches your criteria, these tools can automatically manipulate them, i.e. resize and position them, and move them to a different workspace. You will mist likely need to be logged in on the **Xorg server** (default prior to Ubuntu 21.04). They may not work, or at least be limited, under Wayland.

**wmctrl and xdotool**

If you only need to set up a configuration at login, you can work with `wmctrl` and `xdotool`. With `wmctrl`, you can move to a different workspace, then have your script launch an application. `xdotool` may then be most suited to "search" the window and resize and place it. It features a `--sync` option that causes the command to wait until the window is effectively created.

**devilspie or devilspie2**

`devilspie2` is a successor of `devilspie` that uses a different syntax (Lua) in the configuration file. With these tools, you define rules in which you state what should happen with a window that matches certain criteria. As soon as such window is created, `devilspie` will manipulate it according to the instructions, i.e., resize and position it, move it to a different workspace, ...

Thus, you could define rules for the specific Firefox windows you want to place during startup. When the windows are created by an autostarter or by a script you run on startup, `devilspie` will manipulate them automatically as they are created.